# How to draw broken bars if entities are duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to draw a broken bar diagram with a list of band members that joined and left a music band.
I managed to draw a grid as I wanted to, but stuck with drawing the bars for band members since they are repeating.
I know how to make it when band members are unique but date columns are repeating, f.e.: Year_start1, Year_end1, Year_start2, Year_end2, etc.
But stuck with when band members are duplicating.
So, each person should be presented only once in the y axis with a set of broken bars (if person joined the band more than once).
I appreciate any help!

Code example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame([['Bill', 1972, 1974],
                       ['Bill', 1976, 1978],
                       ['Bill', 1967, 1971],
                       ['Danny', 1969, 1975],
                       ['Danny', 1976, 1977],
                       ['James', 1971, 1972],
                       ['Marshall', 1967, 1975]],
                      columns=['Person', 'Year_start', 'Year_left'])
print(result)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

persons = result.Person.unique()
person_count = len(persons)
ybound = len(persons)*10
ystep = int(ybound/person_count)
numbers = range(5, ybound, ystep)

ax.set_ylim(0, ybound)
ax.set_xlim(min(result.Year_start)-1, max(result.Year_left)+1)
ax.set_xlabel('Years')
ax.set_yticks(numbers, labels=persons)


ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I guess I should use a "for" loop and put the dataframe in "zip", but not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you expect exactly, but you could manually plot the bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

ys = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(result['Person'].unique())}

ax = plt.subplot()

height = 0.5

for row in result.itertuples():
    y = ys[row.Person]
    x0 = row.Year_start
    x1 = row.Year_left
    #                         bottom left corner  width    height
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle((x0, y - height/2), x1 - x0, height,
                              facecolor='grey')
    ax.add_patch(rect)

ax.set_ylim(0-height, len(ys)-1+height)
ax.set_xlim(result['Year_start'].min()-1, result['Year_left'].max()+1)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(ys)), list(ys))
```

*NB. Danny has overlapping dates, which are thus overlapping. If this is not expected, please clarify.*

Output:

[image]

#### using `broken_barh`:

```
ax = plt.subplot()

height = 0.5
for y, (name, g) in enumerate(result.groupby('Person')):
    ax.broken_barh(list(zip(g['Year_start'],
                            g['Year_left']-g['Year_start'])),
                   (y-height/2, height)
                   )
names = sorted(result['Person'].unique())
ax.set_ylim(0-height, len(names)-1+height)
ax.set_xlim(result['Year_start'].min()-1, result['Year_left'].max()+1)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(names)), names)
```

Comment: "Danny has overlapping dates, which are thus overlapping. If this is not expected, please clarify." >> Yep, sorry, its a typo, fixed it.

Thank you! Didn't know that I can draw the bars manually this way.
I saw in documentation that I can drew them using ax.broken_barh: ax.broken_barh([(1968, 1969), (1970, 1971)], (10, 9), facecolors='tab:blue')
But I wanted to make the code more flexible.
I guess the same method can be applied when using ax.broken_barh?

Comment: Yes you can! See update ;)

Comment: Btw, a quick question, if I will define a list of colors: 
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'brown', 'black', 'tab:orange']

and add a facecolors=random.sample(colors, 1) parameter inside ax.broken_barh in your code, why do the bar colors are still repeating sometimes between persons?

Comment: Nevermind and sorry for bothering, I finally found at least 2 ways to make this working =)
1) using facecolors=colors[y]
2) using colormap